# OS X Mail: Search within message (including header)

Tags: macos, mail.app, search

I would like to search within an individual email message using OS X Mail version 5.3 or above (Lion, Mountain Lion). I would like this search to include the email header.

Using the menu item `Edit > Find > Find…` or `Command-F` via the keyboard I am able to search the entire message, exclusive of the header. I would like to search the header, also.

An example of how this would be used: An email message is sent to hundreds of recipients which you want to search to find a specific email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After months of assuming there was no solution to my inquiry, I stumbled on a way to search the *entire* contents of an individual OS X Mail Message, **including headers.**

First open the email message you want to search **in it's own window.** *Before* initiating your search, select the menu item `View > Message > Raw Source` or alternately `Option-Command-U` from the keyboard. This will bring forward a new menu with the entire plain-text content of your message, including extraneous information such as headers.

If you search this *Raw Source* version of your message using `Command-F` or `Edit > Find > Find…` from the menu, the search will include *everything* in the message, including the headers.

> Note: Although I'm currently using OS X Mail version 6.5, I verified that this technique also works at least back to version 5.3.

Comment: An update for Mail Version 7.1 (1827) Mavericks 10.9.1: It is no longer possible to search the *Raw Source* window with `Command-F` or `Edit>Find>Find…` However, you *can* copy the entire window and paste it into a word processor or *TextEdit* where you **can** do a search of the entire message, including headers. Not sure why Apple took this capability out of the *Raw Source* window, but hopefully it will be fixed in future versions.

Comment: Well, it's now back with Yosemite and El Capitan (Mail versions 8 and 9). You can once again use the search function when viewing the *Raw Source* of an email message!

Answer (score 1):

The search bar in Mountain Lion's mail allows you to do a very minimal amount of searching in the headers (for example, you can search on to:, but not cc: or reply-to:).  As a result, I think that you're firmly in AppleScript territory to accomplish this task.

Depending on how specific your goal is, you might find some existing AppleScripts that already meet your needs.  The [archives of the AppleScript users mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/) is probably a good starting point, there are plenty of Apple Mail scripts there.

If this is really important to you, you might want to consider trying out Outlook:Mac.  It has a significantly better AppleScript dictionary than Mail.app, and you might be able to meet your goal in that application better than in Mail.app.